# cucumber plugin needs to be re-install every time eclipse is restarted

Tags: eclipse, cucumber, gherkin

I have installed cucumber plugin on eclipse. It works fine for the first time after you installed. But later it does not identify step definitions. until cucumber plugin is reinstalled again.

Tried with 2 different versions of eclipse.

I have one cucumber dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>6.6.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

and

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>6.6.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Can you suggest what I am missing

--update adding cucumber version and eclipse version
[image]

[image]

Comment: There are many ways to install something into Eclipse. Please tell the exact steps to reproduce the issue and the exact version of the Eclipse you use.

Comment: added screenshot for version and I have installed using eclipse market. to reproduce the issue please follow these step 1: install cucumber step2: Gherkins work fine when you do crtl+click it navigates to step definition. step3: close eclipse step4: again go to eclipse and when you try crtl+click doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it works for you as i have faced similar issues before.
Try converting to cucumber project by Configure -> Convert to Cucumber project
[image]

Comment: I had tried this.... It works sometimes & sometimes there is no change